# How to make Play framework 1.2.x resolve dependencies published locally by sbt, transitively?

Tags: playframework, sbt, ivy

I'm using Play framework with the Scala module. I've factored out some code into a separate library and built it and published it locally using `sbt publish-local`. Now I need `play dependencies` to find that library and its dependencies.

What I have so far is this, in my `~/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml` file:

```
<ivy-settings>
<settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
      <filesystem name="libraries">
        <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/local/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/local/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[ext]s/[artifact].[ext]" />
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

This enables Play to find my library, but unfortunately it ignores *its* dependencies and falsely claims that I don't need them any more and they can be deleted from lib/.

Comment: could you post the ivy.xml for the artifact and maybe the relevant output from ivy?

Comment: @oers I'm never calling ivy directly myself so I'm not sure which is its output. The `ivy.xml` output by sbt contains dependencies as expected, but `strace` shows that `play dependencies` is never even reading that file. Instead, it's reading an xml file from cache that doesn't contain any dependencies. Even when I delete the ivy2 cache, it still does the same thing (creating that file first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `--debug` option to `play dependencies`, I found that for some reason, Play was using "ivy" as the artifact name for the ivy file, instead of my library's name. So as a quick workaround, since I only have one library at the moment, I just changed `[artifact]` to my actual artifact name in the `ivy` element above.

I filed a [Play bug report](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1311-ivy-file-cannot-be-found-because-play-looks-in-wrong-place).